# Android: is there a way to dump crash logs locally on test device with no computer connected

Tags: android, android-studio, segmentation-fault, crash

I'm experiencing pesky SIGSEGV faults in my Android app. They are inconsistent to reproduce and mostly happen after my app has been restarted a couple of times. The problem is, when the app restarts, Android Studio stops showing the logs, making it very hard for me to figure out what the issue is. When I restart the app using the Android Studio restart button, it loads a fresh install of the app onto my phone, which is an issue because the errors don't seem to happen on very fresh installs.

My question is: can I somehow have Android Studio still show the live logs WITHOUT reinstalling the app every time, OR can I run the app without being connected to any PC, and dump a crash log file locally to the phone when the app crashes, so that I can open the logs *later on*?

Comment: you can implement crashlytics in your application. This way if the crash will occur it will show in crashlystics dashboard

Comment: @primo Crashlytics will not capture native android crashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Filtering logcat**

> The problem is, when the app restarts, Android Studio stops showing the logs, making it very hard for me to figure out what the issue is.

It sounds like the logcat in android studio is filtering by application. You can change it to `no filter` and set the text filter to your application's id. This way the logcat will not be cleared once the application process dies/restarts.

**Extracting the tombstones**

Since this is an Android native crash it will not be sent to bug capturing software such as Crashlytics or Bugfender etc.. you can pull the tombstone[s] directly from the device with adb.

`adb bugreport bugreport.zip`

Once extracted, the tombstones will be under path `/bugreport/FS/data/tombstones/`.

Typically 10 tombstones will get saved to device storage but will get overwritten by earlier native crashes once the limit to the number of retained tombstones has been met.

[Android documentation: Using bugreport](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/bug-report)

[Android documentation: Debugging tombstones](https://source.android.com/docs/core/tests/debug)

Comment: Setting it to `no filter` indeed helped me see the crash logs, even after a restart. I haven't been able to pinpoint what's actually causing the crash: they happen very often when I rotate my device, causing the Activity to restart and the traceback implies it happens somewhere in my setContentView call, but other times I will just be using my app without creating new Activities and the crash log will not contain any of my own code. This probably warrants an entirely new SO post.